# Retrieving text from twitter account using BeautifulSoup and Splinter

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, splinter

I am trying to retrieve the text from the latest tweet from https://twitter.com/marswxreport?lang=en

I have tried the following:

```
    twitter_url = 'https://twitter.com/marswxreport?lang=en'
    browser.visit(twitter_url)
    html = browser.html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tweet = soup.find('span', {'class':"css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"}) # css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"
    print(tweet.text)
```

However, it throws an error stating that `"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"` and the `soup.find_all()` returns an empty list.

Upon inspection of the twitter page:

```
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">InSight sol 363 (2019-12-04) low -99.8ºC (-147.6ºF) high -21.1ºC (-5.9ºF)
winds from the SSE at 5.8 m/s (13.0 mph) gusting to 20.3 m/s (45.4 mph)
pressure at 6.60 hPa</span>
```

What I want is to extract "InSight sol 363 (2019-12-04) low -99.8ºC (-147.6ºF) high -21.1ºC (-5.9ºF) winds from the SSE at 5.8 m/s (13.0 mph) gusting to 20.3 m/s (45.4 mph) pressure at 6.60 hPa"

Answer (score 3):

This is because the tag you are trying to scrape loads using javascript after the html page is loaded. So what you are getting as an html doesn't even contain the tag you are looking for. This is why BeautifulSoup is unable to find the tag and NoneType and empty lists are generated when trying to find it.

I would suggest using selenium webdriver to grab the html page as it processes the javascript before returning the html.

You can replace your html get code with following snippet.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(twitter_url)
html = driver.page_source
driver.close()
```